# C++ выдаёт неправильные числа

Tags: c++

Дело в том, что недавно начал изучать C++. вовремя написания первой простой программы столкнулся с проблемой, что на выводе программы выдаёт не те числа, что были присвоены этой переменной с целочисленным значением (т.е. вместо 0 - 48, при добавлении пробелов с той или иной стороны кардинально изменяется число и т.д.)

Код прилагается

```
using namespace std;
int main () {
    int num = '0';
    cout << num << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Кавычки уберите!

Comment: Я долго думал над этим вопросом, но, оказалось, ответ лежал на самой поверхности. Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: ASCII-код символа 0 имеет значение сорок восемь, так что этот код обязан выводить 48

Comment: @Harry, это апострофы.

Comment: @Qwertiy А чем они отличаются от одинарных кавычек?...

Comment: @Harry, тем что кавычки по умолчанию двойные...

Comment: @Qwertiy Паскалистам не скажите только...

Answer (score -1):

Здесь все просто, вы создаете переменную типа Int: Int - переменные хранящие целочисленные данные (натуральные числа), соответственно:

`int a = 10`

вот так должны создаваться переменные, никаких апострофов и кавычек быть там не должно.

При ваших апострофах компилятор выводит данные из таблицы ASCII, в этой таблице 0 соответствует числу 48.